# NDK sample native-audio: couldn't find "libnative-audio-jni.so"

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am at point of using NDK in android studio for my new project. I just installed NDK and imported a sample project inside the NDK package named native-audio. I tried several times to run the project but it still returns

```
 Process: com.example.nativeaudio, PID: 5895
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.nativeaudio-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.nativeaudio-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libnative-audio-jni.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
        at com.example.nativeaudio.NativeAudio.<clinit>(NativeAudio.java:313)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

It will be great help for me if someone could figure out the things and explain actually what happens on that code. I have already gone through almost all the links available in the StackOverflow but no hopefull leads.

**EDIT**
app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nativeaudio"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel 9
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 9

        buildConfigFields {
            create() {
                type "int"
                name "VALUE"
                value "1"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "native-audio-jni"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
        }
    }
     //    productFlavors {
   //        create("flavor1") {
//            applicationId "com.example.nativeaudio"
//        }
//    }

    // Configures source set directory.
    sources {
        main {
            java {
                source {
                    srcDir "src"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

build.gradle

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

my project structure is:

[image]

Comment: could u plz share project structure?

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: May be libnative-audio-jni.so is not compiled and not recognized as a library. Post your build.gradle

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-audio  check this one

Comment: did you add before CFlags.add("-std=c99") and         ldLibs.addAll(["android","OpenSLES", "log"]) after moduleName "native-audio-jni"

Comment: I have edited the question with both gradle files and screenshot of my project explorer

Comment: @g2o no. Is that required?

Comment: oh yes everything is important ...maybe is not the solution but if in main samples is set, I really will not miss that part ;)

Comment: I have added those lines in app/build.gradle but no change

Comment: @Reaz Murshed : I havn't seen any .so files in my project structure.

Comment: @g2o I really dont when then .so files would create and I havent seem them in my project structure yet.

Comment: You need to build a .so file by compiling the native-audio-jni.c. JNI can't access the functions inside the c file directly. It communicates through JNI. You need to go through the JNI documentation.

Comment: Ok. I have gone through one. bt no luck.

Comment: all the documentation tells about development in eclipse and windows. I am using LINUX and Android Studio

Comment: could you create a .so file by compiling the C file?

Comment: yes. I created the .so file